# How execute/open multiple SQL statements in 1 go with ODBC / SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, odbc

What I'm basically trying to do is fire off multiple SQL statements in one go.
This works fine as long as they don't return results.

What I want to do is make a temporary table fill it and join it on my existing data:

```
CREATE TABLE #JaarMaandTable(jaarm int,maandm int)
INSERT INTO #JaarMaandTable (jaarm,maandm) VALUES (2013,9), (2013,10), (2013,11)

SELECT jaarm,maandm, kr.* 
FROM  #JaarMaandTable jm 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT  DATEPART(Month, datum) as maand, DATEPART(Year, datum) as jaar ,count(*) as regels mytable 
   FROM agenda 
   WHERE datum >= '20130901' 
   AND datum <= '20131130' 
   GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, datum), DATEPART(Month, datum)
)kr  ON jm.jaarm = kr.jaar AND jm.maandm = kr.maand ORDER BY jaarm, maandm
```

This is to make use of a temp table to split up results in months even when there's no data for those months.

It works fine in query analyser.

When I try to use "open" on this query, it tells me it doesn't return a cursor.
When I "execsql" it, it won't return results.
When I split it up, it immediately forgets the #temptable.

Comment: You don't need to create a temporary table to do what you want.  Would a single query statement fix your problem?

Comment: Using ADO with SQLOLEDB would work without problems.

Comment: Show your code please. Normally, you use a different command when executing a query that doesn't return a result set (`ExecSQL`, or something similar).

Comment: The problem was that with an OEQry.ExeSsql, it executed the SQL fine but didn't return a result set and with OEQry.Open it complained the result is not a cursor type. Splitting it up, then the database "forgot" the temptable between execsql en open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the query using a `with` statement, to avoid the need for a temporary table:

```
with JaarMaandTable(jaarm int,maandm int) as (
       select 2013, 9 union all
       select 2013, 10 union all
       select 2013, 11
      )
SELECT jaarm,maandm, kr.* 
FROM  JaarMaandTable jm 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT  DATEPART(Month, datum) as maand, DATEPART(Year, datum) as jaar ,count(*) as regels mytable 
   FROM agenda 
   WHERE datum >= '20130901' 
   AND datum <= '20131130' 
   GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, datum), DATEPART(Month, datum)
)kr  ON jm.jaarm = kr.jaar AND jm.maandm = kr.maand ORDER BY jaarm, maandm
```

Comment: I had to change JaarMaandTable(jaarm int,maandm int) to JaarMaandTable(jaarm,maandm)  but for the rest it works like a charm.